# apache htaccess rewrite https request_filename

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am looking to optimize some rewrite rules for better loading performance. I am hoping to combine rules to rewrite from HTTP to HTTPS as well as handle rewriting of the filename for GET var.

This is the functioning code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?var=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This was my attempt, which was redirecting to only the %{REQUEST_URI}:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}index.php?var=$1 [R,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, rewrite rules are not parsed for each request if they are in the apache/virtual host config files, rather they are parsed and stored when the server starts.  I'm not certain about .htaccess but I'm pretty sure that once the file has been parsed it is only re-parsed if the timestamp on it changes.

In any case, your combined rule won't work because the redirect to https and the rewrite through index.php are independent actions.  Your combined version will only rewrite things that are NOT https.

Comment: Thanks for providing a better understanding of the main issue. It looks as though I will need to keep my original code as is.